# Multiply phase of a qubit by $2^k$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

Given a qubit in the state $|0\rangle+\exp(2πi/2^n)|1\rangle$, is there a quantum mechanical operator to multiply the phase of the qubit with $2^k$ (where $k \leq n$). Such that:-

> $$|0\rangle+\exp(2πi/2^n)|1\rangle \quad \mathrm{becomes} \quad |0\rangle+\exp(2πi/2^{n-k})|1\rangle$$

Comment: Can such an operator be linear?

Comment: (very) related to https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/12634/55

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an operator (I used notation from IBM Q quantum computer, same operator is called $R1$ in Microsoft Q# language)
$$
U1(\varphi)=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & \mathrm{e}^{i\varphi}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Setting $\varphi = \frac{2\pi }{2^n}(2^k - 1)$ and applying on your qubit in state $|0\rangle + \mathrm{exp}(\frac{2\pi i}{2^n})|1\rangle$ you will get qubit in desired state because
$$
\mathrm{exp}\Big(\frac{2\pi i}{2^n}\Big)\,\mathrm{exp}\Big(\frac{2\pi i}{2^n}(2^k - 1)\Big) = \mathrm{exp}\Big(\frac{2\pi i}{2^n}2^k\Big)
$$